# how can i get Students Grades using Grade,studets tables

Tags: sql

how can i get students grades using these 2 tables?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grade](
 [ID] [int] NULL,
 [From] [int] NULL,
 [To] [int] NULL,
 [Grade] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar NULL,
    [Score] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: uhm ... this is just one table ...

Comment: Suggestions - Make ID and Name both Non-null. Assuming Grade.ID refers to Student.ID, make it a foreign key reference. SQL can only enforce rules if you tell it what the rules are, and they're well thought out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets take a guess that the Students table has a column (probably an identity column) called 'ID' which is the students' unique identifier. 
Let's also assume that the Grade.ID field is a foreign key reference to the Student table (I know it doesn't say that, but it's probably a good idea.)

In that case, try this (untested code):

```
SELECT Student.Name, Grade.Grade, Grade.From, Grade.To
FROM Student, Grade
WHERE Student.ID = Grade.ID
ORDER BY Student.ID, Grade.To
```

That ought to give you a list of students, with their grades in ID order.
It will repeat the student name for each grade record however (assuming no null values, of course.)

If you want one student instance with a list of grades, that's significantly harder.

(Btw, the more and better information in the initial question, the better the answers you're likely to get.)

---

Ok - second shot, now I understand the table structure:

```
SELECT Students.Name,  (select Grades.GradeName from Grades where Students.Score <= Grades.ScoreTo AND Students.Score > Grades.ScoreFrom) AS Grade
FROM Students
```

I changed the names a little to make them more obvious and distinct (having the same name for a table and a field on that table is confusing.)

This should give you the results you're looking for. 
BUT - you must ensure that your data is clean - if you have overlapping ranges, you will get a multiple sub-query return (which will fail.) You can overcome this with a 'SELECT TOP 1' restriction, but it's messy.

Comment: thanx a lot dear.but its not like that. there is not foreign key.i added 2 tables now.check them and give me a solution

Comment: 1 0 39 F
2 40 54 S
3 55 64 C
4 65 74 B
5 75 100 A

ID Name Score
2 student1 96
3 student2 90
4 student3 16
5 student4 92
6 student5 56

these are da tables

Comment: Ok, so is there a relationship between the tables? If not, I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grade](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [From] [int] NOT NULL,
 [To] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Grade] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Grade] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

this is da first table

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Score] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

this is da second table

Comment: Ok, so two tables, with no obvious relationship - what information is it that you want? (I'm really trying to be helpful here, but I'm not seeing what it is you're after.)

Comment: i want to get student names with there Grade
ID     From    To      Grade
1 0 39 F
2 40 54 S
3 55 64 C
4 65 74 B
5 75 100 A

Comment: in Grade table has a marks ranges. lets say STUDENT1 get 25 marks
and Grade table says that from 0 to 39 marks is F
so i want to get da result "STUDENT1 F" like wise for all student table

Comment: Ahh .. ok, so the Grade table holds a grade ID, with a (presumably non-overlapping score range. You want the students' score to be interpreted as a grade. I think I see what you want now.

Comment: thats rite.that is which i wanted

Comment: Updated the answer. Note the name changes (I did it for clarity for myself.) And note the caveats on the solution.
This is a correlated sub-query, and it has risks if the data isn't clean.

Comment: And I'd also suggest a design change to make it safer. Rather than a from-to - I think it would be better to have a minimum mark system - so you have if your mark is 75 or greater, 'A', otherwise if greater than 65 then 'B', etc. This this can be done:
select Students.Name,  (select top 1 Grades.GradeName from Grades where Students.Score < Grades.ScoreTo order by Grades.ScoreTo Desc) AS Grade
from Students